# How to find the 1st date of previous month in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am not able to run this function, is there any changes in this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GetFirstDateofMonth] 
(@Date as DateTime)  

RETURNS DateTime AS  
BEGIN 

Declare @FirstDate DateTime 
Set @FirstDate = DateAdd(Day, 1, @Date - Day(@Date) + 1) -1

RETURN @FirstDate

END
```

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [GetLastDateofMonth] 
(@Date as DateTime)  

RETURNS DateTime AS  
BEGIN 

Declare @LastDate DateTime 
Set @LastDate = DateAdd(Month, 1, @Date - Day(@Date) + 1) -1

RETURN @LastDate

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it relative to "now":

```
select subdate(adddate(last_day(now()), 1), interval 2 month)
```

replace `now()` with whatever you want if it's relative to some date other than "now"